# Is there anyway working with schemas in Deno?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, deno

I am trying to store and work with a similar to following structure data using Deno and MongoDB.

```
   [
      {
        id: "AAPL",
        stockData: [
          { date: 1634601600, summary: [Object] },
          { date: 1634688000, summary: [Object] },
          { date: 1634774400, summary: [Object] },
          { date: 1634860800, summary: [Object] }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "MSFT",
        stockData: [
          { date: 1634601600, summary: [Object] },
          { date: 1634688000, summary: [Object] }
        ]
      }
  ]
```

And `[Object]` is something like:

```
  {
    date: "1646956800",
    summary: { open: 287.96, high: 289.51, low: 279.43, close: 280.07, volume: 27209330 }
  }
```

As Deno is new and I know there is no compatibility with Deno and Mongoose at the moment, I have some questions:

1. Is there any alternative to Mongoose for Deno or any better way to work with schemas?
2. If I want to do a big project should I stop working with Deno and return to using NodeJS at the moment?
3. Can I convert my Deno code to NodeJS-TypeScript code or it is better to rewrite it in JavaScript?

I am a mediocre programmer and new in web development. I am trying to write my first real/commercial project and I don't want to get stuck because of lack of abilities in Deno, also want to use the latest technology and don't want to rewrite the project with a new technology after I completed it. So I don't know should I keep my project using Deno or rewrite it to NodeJS and forget the Deno?

Comment: Re: code transformation Deno -> Node: see https://github.com/denoland/dnt

Comment: @jsejcksn: Do you recommend to use NodeJS with Typescript or Javascript?

Comment: TypeScript all the way!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mongoDriver for Deno : https://deno.land/x/mongo.
It is not the only one available on deno.land/x, you can make a search from deno.land website.